# How can I upgrade Carbon with Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, php-carbon

I tried in cmd "composer require nesbot/carbon" but I got this:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1

    - laravel/framework v5.6.27 requires nesbot/carbon 1.25.* -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[1.25.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - laravel/framework v5.6.27 requires nesbot/carbon 1.25.* -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[1.25.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - laravel/framework v5.6.27 requires nesbot/carbon 1.25.* -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[1.25.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.6.27, required as 5.6.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.6.27].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: Do you need a new feature or something?  It looks like Laravel 5.6 has only allowed version 1.25 so you'd be potentially breaking that dependency by upgrading to something newer.

Comment: Unless you want a new feature of Carbon there is no need to upgrade it. The error says itself, it's a requirement for Laravel to maintain that versionfor the 5.6 version

Answer (score 4):

I don't recommend doing this without extreme caution because there may be a reason why Laravel, or any of your other dependencies, require a very strict version of a package.

With that said, Composer does include a neat trick to alias versions to get around this by specifying an alias version in `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "nesbot/carbon": "1.32.0 as 1.25.0"
},
```

Note the `as 1.25.0` which will trick other packages into thinking `1.32.0` is equivalent to `1.25.0` for dependencies. This trick requires exact versions.

Comment: My reason is to use CarbonPeriod,  which is not available in this version.

Comment: And doesn't allow me to upgrade with your suggestion either.

Comment: And maybe you can just add the class to your Project say in `app\Util\CarbonPeriod.php` https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/src/Carbon/CarbonPeriod.php

Answer (score 2):

Carbon 2 is officially supported by Laravel since the version 5.8, if you want to use it on a lower version, you can follow those steps:

Set explicitly the Carbon version and add the adapter in your composer.json:

```
{
"require": {
    "nesbot/carbon": "2.21.3 as 1.34.0"
 }
}
```